# Improve performance reading and writing txt files with python

Tags: python

I am using python to manage txt files, read and write several times. But if I have 1000 txt files my code is taking so long time to manage the files.

How can I improve the performance to manage with these files?

I have files with this information:

```
position   temperature
0,0        30,10
1,0        45,12
2,0        20,45 (...)
```

In the first place I need to remove the lines with strings. For taht I search the strings and create new txt file and copy the information without the lines with strings to that new txt file. I get this:

```
0,0       30,10
1,0       45,12
2,0       20,45 (...)
```

Then I replace the , by . in all the files, again creating a new file and coping the information with points to these new files. I get this:

```
0.0      30.10
1.0      45.12
2.0      20.45 (...)
```

Then I need to restrict the information with a minimal position value (a) and a maximum value (b). So in the first column I just want the lines between a and b. Again I create new files and copy the information that I want to these files.

Finally I add a new column to each file with some information.

So, I think that the time consuming in my code is related to the times that I create new files, copy the information and replace the old ones with these new ones.

Maybe this all can be done in one step. I just need to know if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Got any code to share? ...

Comment: My code is too long to put here because it inserted in an application. But I can explain what I need to do. I am going to edit the post.

Comment: Strip everything irrelevant and show us how you access, read and write those files, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing a [mcve]. It's possible that there isn't a lot you can do to speed this up, simply due to the slowness of disk IO, unless you use a SSD for these files. But maybe there are some optimizations that can be made so that your tasks can be performed with reduced file handling. If disk IO isn't the limiting factor, then maybe you will need to use a compiled language for this task, or the time-intensive parts of it.

Comment: Ok. You can certainly combine all those operations so that you don't need to read & write each file multiple times. But we still need to see your code in order to make definite suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You no need to create new files just to delete first lines or replace commas to dots in lines. You could do all work in memory, i.e. read data from file, replace commas to dots, convert values to float, sort them, trim min and max values and write result to file, like this:

```
input_file = open('input_file', 'r')
data = []
input_file.readline() # first line with titles
for line in input_file: # lines with data
    data.append(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.'), line.split()))
input_file.close()

data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
data = data[1:-1]

result_file = open('result_file', 'w')
result_file.writelines(['\t'.join(row) for row in data])

result_file.close()
```

Comment: In this case, the line with strings wasn't removed. How do you remove that?

Comment: As you can see, I write result in new file (without first line), source file can be removed.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But this code doesn't give me what I want. The data is a list of lists and when I write in new file, it appears [1.0,22.15]     [2.0,30.12]     (...) in line. And I whant two columns.

Comment: Please, read code more attentively, there are lines to write two columns in each line: for row in data:
    result_file.writeline('\t'.join(row))

Comment: If I use writeline, gives also an error. It says that a file object does not have an attribute "writeline".

Comment: I get it with this line in the end: result_file.writeline('\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,row)) for row in data). Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I've edited answer, you can use write function in cycle or writelines function with array of strings.

Answer (score -1):

You're definitely doing it the hard way... There are a lot of detail informations missing from your problem's description, but assuming a few things - like the headers are always on the first line, "position" and "temperature" are supposed to be floats etc - here's a code example doing mostly what you describe in a single pass:

```
import sys
from itertools import ifilter

def parse(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        # skip the headers
        f.next()

        # parse data
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            try:
                position, temperature = line.split()
                position = float(position.replace(",", "."))
                temperature = float(temperature.replace(",","."))
            except ValueError as e:
                raise ValueError("Invalid line at %s:#%s" % (path, lineno))

            yield position, temperature


def process(inpath, outpath, minpos, maxpos):
    # warning: exact comparisons on floating points numbers
    # are not safe
    filterpos = lambda r: minpos <= r[0] <= maxpos 

    with open(outpath, "w") as outfile:
        for pos, temp in ifilter(filterpos, parse(inpath)):
            extra_col = compute_something_from(pos, temp)
            out.writeline("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(pos, temp, extra_col))


def compute_something_from(pos, temp):
    # anything
    return pos * (temp / 3.)


def main(*args):
    # TODO : 
    # - clean options / args handling
    # - outfile naming ? 
    minpos = float(args[0])
    maxpos = float(args[1])
    for inpath in args[2:]:
        outpath = inpath + ".tmp"
        process(inpath, outpath, minpos, maxpos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```